# Launching an HTA file using older version of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, hta

I have been given an .hta file from a third party and I am trying to integrate with their software. I can run the .hta file using "Microsoft HTML application host".

The vendor just informed me that their product doesn't work with IE 11, which is the version on my machine. Is there a way that I can specify that the hta file be run with IE 10 or older? I understand that there is a way to do this with .exe's in the registry, but will the same method work for the hta file?

Comment: The HTA itself can be run with IE11, but the HTA tag is not supported. IE9 is the last IE version to run a HTA properly. There might also occur issues with layout and CSS, and some really old non-standard DOM/JS methods/properties are totally removed from the newer IEs, for example `createStyleSheet` is not supported at all, despite of the document mode.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the `<head>` section of your HTA file 
`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">`

Comment: doing this disables the <hta:application> tag

Comment: @spectacularbob That should not happen, IE>9 does that.